# グローバルに pip install したものをみにいかないようにする方法

Tags: python, pip

aws lambda のパッケージを作るときに
足りないライブラリを調べてパッケージに含めるために
pip でグローバルにインストールしたものをみにいかないようにしたいです

どうすれば可能でしょうか？

Cとかだと LD_LIBRARY_PATH みたいなのをいじればできると思うんですが
python でもリンクするライブラリパスを切り替えるようなことってできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> pip でグローバルにインストールしたものをみにいかないようにしたい

パッケージ管理ツールを使い、システム全体でインストールされたライブラリと別のPython環境を作り、その中で作業をすることで求めていることが実現できます。

`pipenv` や `poetry` などが現在メジャーですので、ここから触ってみるのをおすすめします。

[Pipenv: 人間のためのPython開発ワークフロー — pipenv 2018.11.27.dev0 ドキュメント](https://pipenv-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/translate-ja/)

[Poetry documentation (ver. 1.1.6 日本語訳)](https://cocoatomo.github.io/poetry-ja/)

#### 参考

- [PEP 517 – A build-system independent format for source trees | peps.python.org](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/)
- [pipとpipenvとpoetryの技術的・歴史的背景とその展望 - Stimulator](https://vaaaaaanquish.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/03/29/221715#pipenv)

Comment: できました！　ありがとうございます